# Некоректно отображаются цвета, если в координатах фигуры использовать vector3 вместо vector4 и добавлении 4 компоненты в вершином шейдере SharpDX

Tags: sharpdx

vertex.hlsl

```
struct vertexData
{
    float3 position : POSITION;
    float4 color    : COLOR;
};

struct pixelData
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION; // SV - System Value
    float4 color    : COLOR;
};

cbuffer perObjectData : register(b0)
{
    float4x4 worldViewProjectionMatrix;
    float    time;
    int      timeScaling; // matrix 4x4 4 байта 4*4*4 = 64 + 4 + 4 = 72 соответ 4-х компонентному вектору 
    float2   _padding;
}

pixelData vertexShader(vertexData input)
{
    pixelData output = (pixelData)0;
    float4 position = float4(input.position.xyz, 1.0f);

    float scale = 0.5f * sin(time * 0.785f) + 1.0f; //0.785 - скорость масштабирования
    if (timeScaling > 0) // масштабирования
        position.xyz = mul(scale, position.xyz); // mul - multiplication
    output.position = mul(position, worldViewProjectionMatrix); // V * M
    output.color = input.color;
    return output;
}
```

Renderer.cs

```
class Renderer : IDisposable
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct VertexDataStruct
    {
        public Vector3 position;
        public Vector2 texCoord;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PerObjectConstantBuffer
    {
        public Matrix worldViewProjectionMatrix;
        public float time;
        public int timeScaling;
        public Vector2 _padding;
    }

    private DirectX3DGraphics _directX3DGraphics;
    private Device11 _device;
    private DeviceContext _deviceContext;

    private VertexShader _vertexShader;
    private PixelShader _pixelShader;
    private ShaderSignature _shaderSignature;
    private InputLayout _inputLayout;//задаем формат входных данных - описание соотв структуре

    private PerObjectConstantBuffer _perObjectConstantBuffer;
    private Buffer11 _perObjectConstantBufferObject;

    private SamplerState _anisotropicSampler;
    public SamplerState AnisotropicSampler { get => _anisotropicSampler; }
    public Renderer(DirectX3DGraphics directX3DGraphics)
    {
        _directX3DGraphics = directX3DGraphics;
        _device = _directX3DGraphics.Device;
        _deviceContext = _directX3DGraphics.DeviceContext;

        CompilationResult vertexShaderByteCode = 
            ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("vertex.hlsl", "vertexShader", "vs_5_0");
        _vertexShader = new VertexShader(_device, vertexShaderByteCode);
        CompilationResult pixelShaderByteCode =
            ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("pixel.hlsl", "pixelShader", "ps_5_0");
        _pixelShader = new PixelShader(_device, pixelShaderByteCode);

        InputElement[] inputElements = new[]
        {
            new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0),
            new InputElement("TEXCOORD", 0, Format.R32G32_Float, 16, 0)
        };

        _shaderSignature = ShaderSignature.GetInputOutputSignature(vertexShaderByteCode);
        _inputLayout = new InputLayout(_device, _shaderSignature, inputElements);

        Utilities.Dispose(ref vertexShaderByteCode);
        Utilities.Dispose(ref pixelShaderByteCode);

        _deviceContext.InputAssembler.InputLayout = _inputLayout;
        _deviceContext.VertexShader.Set(_vertexShader);
        _deviceContext.PixelShader.Set(_pixelShader);

        SamplerStateDescription samplerStateDescription =
            new SamplerStateDescription
            {
                Filter = Filter.Anisotropic,
                AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
                AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
                AddressW = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
                MipLodBias = 0.0f,
                MaximumAnisotropy = 16, // уровень качетсва результирующей картинки
                ComparisonFunction = Comparison.Never,
                BorderColor = new SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawColor4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                MinimumLod = 0,
                MaximumLod = float.MaxValue
            };
        _anisotropicSampler = new SamplerState(_directX3DGraphics.Device, samplerStateDescription);
    }


    public void CreateConstantBuffer()
    {
        _perObjectConstantBufferObject = new Buffer11(
            _device, Utilities.SizeOf<PerObjectConstantBuffer>(), 
            ResourceUsage.Dynamic, BindFlags.ConstantBuffer,
            CpuAccessFlags.Write, ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            0);
    }

    public void SetPerObjectConstantBuffer(float time, int timeScaling)
    {
        _perObjectConstantBuffer.time = time;
        _perObjectConstantBuffer.timeScaling = timeScaling;
    }

    public void BeginRender()
    {
        _directX3DGraphics.ClearBuffers(Color.Black); //фоновый цвет для буфера кадров
    }

    public void UpdatePerObjectConstantBuffers(Matrix world, Matrix view,
        Matrix projection)
    {
        _perObjectConstantBuffer.worldViewProjectionMatrix =
            Matrix.Multiply(Matrix.Multiply(world, view), projection);
        _perObjectConstantBuffer.worldViewProjectionMatrix.Transpose();
        DataStream dataStream; // поток с помощью которого будем заливать данные в буфер память
        _deviceContext.MapSubresource(_perObjectConstantBufferObject,// генерируем
            MapMode.WriteDiscard,
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags.None,
            out dataStream);

        dataStream.Write(_perObjectConstantBuffer); // заливаем
        _deviceContext.UnmapSubresource(_perObjectConstantBufferObject, 0); // отключаемся
        _deviceContext.VertexShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, _perObjectConstantBufferObject); 
    }

    public void SetTexture(Texture texture)
    {
        _deviceContext.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, texture.ShaderResourceView);
        _deviceContext.PixelShader.SetSampler(0, texture.SamplerState);
    }


    public void RenderMeshObject(MeshObject meshObject)
    {
        _deviceContext.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList;
        _deviceContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, meshObject.VertexBufferBinding);
        _deviceContext.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(meshObject.IndicesBufferObject,
            Format.R32_UInt, 0);
        _deviceContext.DrawIndexed(meshObject.IndicesCount, 0, 0);
    }

    public void EndRender()
    {
        _directX3DGraphics.SwapChain.Present(1, PresentFlags.Restart);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Utilities.Dispose(ref _anisotropicSampler);
        Utilities.Dispose(ref _perObjectConstantBufferObject);
        Utilities.Dispose(ref _inputLayout);
        Utilities.Dispose(ref _shaderSignature);
        Utilities.Dispose(ref _pixelShader);
        Utilities.Dispose(ref _vertexShader);
    }
}
```

Loader.cs

```
class Loader : IDisposable
{
    private DirectX3DGraphics _directX3DGraphics;
    private ImagingFactory _imagingFactory;

    public Loader(DirectX3DGraphics directX3DGraphics)
    {
        _directX3DGraphics = directX3DGraphics;
        _imagingFactory = new ImagingFactory();
    }

    public Texture LoadTextureFromFile(string fileName, SamplerState samplerState)
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = new BitmapDecoder(_imagingFactory,
            fileName, DecodeOptions.CacheOnDemand);
        BitmapFrameDecode bitmapFirstFrame = decoder.GetFrame(0);

        Utilities.Dispose(ref decoder);

        FormatConverter formatConverter = new FormatConverter(_imagingFactory);
        formatConverter.Initialize(bitmapFirstFrame, PixelFormat.Format32bppRGBA,
            BitmapDitherType.None, null, 0.0f, BitmapPaletteType.Custom);

        int stride = formatConverter.Size.Width * 4; //одна строка пикселей
        DataStream buffer = new DataStream(formatConverter.Size.Height * stride, true, true);
        formatConverter.CopyPixels(stride, buffer);

        int width = formatConverter.Size.Width;
        int height = formatConverter.Size.Height;

        Texture2DDescription texture2DDescription = new Texture2DDescription()
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            MipLevels = 1,
            ArraySize = 1,
            Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
            SampleDescription = _directX3DGraphics.SampleDescription, //не где-то не совпадет, работать не будет
            BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource | BindFlags.RenderTarget,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None
        };

        Texture2D textureObject = new Texture2D(_directX3DGraphics.Device, texture2DDescription,
            new DataRectangle(buffer.DataPointer, stride));
        ShaderResourceViewDescription shaderResourceViewDescription = new ShaderResourceViewDescription()
        {
            Dimension = ShaderResourceViewDimension.Texture2D,
            Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
            Texture2D = new ShaderResourceViewDescription.Texture2DResource
            {
                MostDetailedMip = 0,
                MipLevels = -1
            }
        };
        ShaderResourceView shaderResourceView = new ShaderResourceView(_directX3DGraphics.Device, textureObject,
            shaderResourceViewDescription);
        Utilities.Dispose(ref formatConverter);

        return new Texture(textureObject, shaderResourceView, width, height, samplerState);

    }

    public MeshObject MakeOctahedron(Vector4 position, float yaw, float pitch, float roll)
    {
        Renderer.VertexDataStruct[] vertices =
            new Renderer.VertexDataStruct[]
            {
                //Верхняя часть
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 1
                {
                    position =new Vector3(-2.0f,  0.0f, -2.0f), //0
                    texCoord = new Vector2(517f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 1
                {
                    position = new Vector3(0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f),
                    texCoord = new Vector2(848f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 1
                {
                    position = new Vector3(-2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f),//3
                    texCoord = new Vector2(682f/1200f, 170f/1200f)
                },


                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 2
                {
                    position = new Vector3(-2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), //3
                    texCoord = new Vector2(1178f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 2
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f),
                    texCoord = new Vector2(848f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 2
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), //2
                    texCoord = new Vector2(1013f/1200f, 742f/1200f)
                },


                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 3
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), //2
                    texCoord = new Vector2(1013f/1200f, 742f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 3
                {
                    position = new Vector3(0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f),
                    texCoord = new Vector2(848f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 3
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f),//1
                    texCoord = new Vector2(682f/1200f, 742f/1200f)
                },


                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 4
                {
                    position = new Vector3(2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f),//1
                    texCoord = new Vector2(682f/1200f, 742f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 4
                {
                    position = new Vector3(0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f),
                    texCoord = new Vector2(848f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 4
                {
                    position = new Vector3(-2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f),//0
                    texCoord = new Vector2(517f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                },



                //Нижняя часть
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 5
                {
                    position =new Vector3(-2.0f,  0.0f, -2.0f), //0
                    texCoord = new Vector2(517f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 5
                {
                    position = new Vector3(0.0f, -4.0f, 0.0f),
                    texCoord = new Vector2(351f/1200f, 742f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 5
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (-2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), //3
                    texCoord = new Vector2(186f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                },


                 new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 6
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (-2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), //3
                    texCoord = new Vector2(186f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 6
                {
                    position = new Vector3(0.0f, -4.0f, 0.0f),
                    texCoord = new Vector2(351f/1200f, 742f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 6
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), //2
                    texCoord = new Vector2(22f/1200f, 741f/1200f)
                },


                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 7
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), //2
                    texCoord = new Vector2(517f/1200f, 1027f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 7
                {
                    position = new Vector3(0.0f, -4.0f, 0.0f),
                    texCoord = new Vector2(351f/1200f, 742f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 7
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f), //1
                    texCoord = new Vector2(682f/1200f, 742f/1200f)
                },


                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 8
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f), //1
                    texCoord = new Vector2(682f/1200f, 742f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 8
                {
                    position = new Vector3(0.0f, -4.0f, 0.0f),
                    texCoord = new Vector2(351f/1200f, 742f/1200f)
                },
                new Renderer.VertexDataStruct // side 8
                {
                    position = new Vector3 (-2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f), //0
                    texCoord = new Vector2(517f/1200f, 457f/1200f)
                }

            };
        uint[] indices = new uint[]
        {
           //Верхняя часть
            0, 1, 2,
            3, 4, 5,
            6, 7, 8,
            9, 10, 11,
            
            //Нижняя часть
            14, 13, 12,
            17, 16,15,
            20, 19, 18,
            23, 22, 21
        };

        return new MeshObject(_directX3DGraphics, position,
            yaw, pitch, roll, vertices, indices);
    }



    public void Dispose()
    {
        Utilities.Dispose(ref _imagingFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то `VertexDataStruct` совсем не совпадает с `vertexData`